# saving blob file in oracle using php

Tags: php, oracle

please tell me how can i insert pdf or doc files into oracle blob field .

this is the code which i use for varchr data type and this is fine but how can i save the files into blob data type please help me !!!

```
if(isset($_POST['elm1'])) {

$pdata=$_POST['elm1'];  
$profile_name=$_POST['profilename'];
$profile_id=$_POST['profileid'];
$query = "insert into prepaid_profiles values('$profile_id' , '$profile_name','$pdata')";
$result = oci_parse($dbc,$query);
oci_execute($result);
oci_close($dbc);
```

Comment: Why save full file to DB when you can save it on server and in DB write only reference?

Comment: i need that the file save in DB not in server .

Comment: i am using tinymce editor and i want to get the content of the editor and save it in the blob field of DB

Comment: I think what you are looking for was already answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11970258/upload-images-as-blobs-in-oracle-using-php

Answer (score 0):

When user uploads file, save it in server, show only link to it. When saved text from editor, you save only link (with rest of text). File is still on server.

But if you really need to make your database huge and slowly, read uploaded file with `file_get_contents`, that convert it to `base64` and save to database long string (no idea why it's better).

TinyMCE don't need file content in `<textarea>`.