# Unable to store Image in BLOB

Tags: php, oracle, oracle12c

I am trying to store my images into my database using php and oracle 12c but it does'not allow me to insert not giving any error

```
ORDER_ID                                  NOT NULL NUMBER(38)
RX_IMAGE1                                 NULL BLOB
RX_IMAGE3                                 NULL BLOB
RX_IMAGE4                                 NULL BLOB
CREATE_DATE_TIME                          NULL DATE
LAST_UPDATE_DATE_TIME                     NULL DATE
RX_IMAGE2                                 NULL BLOB
```

```
public function prc()
{
    if ($this->input->post('send_prescription') == 'send_prescription') {
        $prescriptionInfo['rx_image1'] = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['pic']['tmp_name']));
        $result = $this->PatientModel->setPrescription($prescriptionInfo);
        if ($result == TRUE) {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('new_val', '1');
        } else {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('new_val', '0');
        }
    }
    $customer_id = $this->session->userdata('CUSTOMER_ID');
    $data['patient_data'] = $this->PatientModel->getPatientsByCustid($customer_id);
    $this->load->view('prescription/new_prescription', $data);
}
```

Not giving any error

Comment: Better do not store image on db, db should store links to images.

Comment: How are you doing it? Post the code that you're using. Only the Oracle SQL/PL/SQL statements.

Comment: ```
public function prc(){
if($this->input->post('send_prescription')=='send_prescription'){ 
$prescriptionInfo['rx_image1'] = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['pic']['tmp_name'])); 
$result = $this->PatientModel->setPrescription($prescriptionInfo);
if($result==TRUE){
$this->session->set_flashdata('new_val','1'); 
}else{
$this->session->set_flashdata('new_val','0');
}
}
$customer_id = $this->session->userdata('CUSTOMER_ID');
$data['patient_data'] = $this->PatientModel->getPatientsByCustid($customer_id);
$this->load->view('prescription/new_prescription',$data);
}
```

Comment: Please **[edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57002046/edit)** the question and add the code there, properly formatted. Code in comments is unreadable. Also, this seems PHP code and, if so, `addslashes()` is a nice way to corrupt binary data (and the question is mis-tagged).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Upload images as BLOBs in Oracle using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11970258/upload-images-as-blobs-in-oracle-using-php)

Answer (score 1):

A Plain `INSERT INTO` doesn't work for BLOB inserts. You've got to use a standard method. Observe carefully in the below code example.

*Table*

```
CREATE TABLE t (id NUMBER, img BLOB);   
INSERT INTO t VALUES (1, EMPTY_BLOB()); --A simple blob to test
```

*Directory*

```
CREATE OR REPLACE DIRECTORY MY_DIR AS '/tmp/images';
GRANT READ, WRITE ON DIRECTORY MY_DIR TO user_name;
```

*Code to Insert*

```
DECLARE
  src_lob  BFILE := BFILENAME('MY_DIR', 'keyboard.jpg'); 
      --MY_DIR refers to the directory in the server where your blob files are stored.
     --It should have been created and relevant permissions be given to your schema 
     --as shown above.
  dest_lob BLOB;
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO t VALUES(2, EMPTY_BLOB())
     RETURNING img INTO dest_lob;

  DBMS_LOB.OPEN(src_lob, DBMS_LOB.LOB_READONLY);
  DBMS_LOB.LoadFromFile( DEST_LOB => dest_lob,
                         SRC_LOB  => src_lob,
                         AMOUNT   => DBMS_LOB.GETLENGTH(src_lob) );
  DBMS_LOB.CLOSE(src_lob);

  COMMIT;
END;
/
```

For PHP, refer to [**this documentation**](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17781_01/appdev.112/e18555/ch_twelve_blobs.htm#TDPPH183) under PHP Developer's Guide which basically explains  the required code/steps using the above technique.

Comment: I am using the below code to insert file in db 

insert into PRESCRIPTION_IMAGES(ORDER_ID,RX_IMAGE1,CREATE_DATE_TIME,LAST_UPDATE_DATE_TIME)values('26','89504e470d0a1a0a5c305c305c300d494844525c305c3001305c305c30011508065c305c305c30679ab9765c305c305c3001735247425c30aece1ce95c305c305c300467414d415c305c30b18f0bfc61055c305c305c3009704859735c305c300ec');

Comment: I am converting image to hex value

Comment: @Sushantkr.kunwar : I've updated the link, please check. There's no need to convert to hex value. Use the suggested method.

Comment: This answer is OK-ish if you have access to the DB file system, but many developers don't.  It's also complex.  Just use the PHP solution given in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11970258/upload-images-as-blobs-in-oracle-using-php